# What type of template are WP media-modal's templates?

Tags: javascript, media-modal, backbone, underscore

I was looking at the Wordpress templates (html that's written to the page instead of awkwardly adding strings in JS).

There are a lot of templates like this in a post editor for example:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-uploader-status-error">
        <span class="upload-error-filename">{{{ data.filename }}}</span>
        <span class="upload-error-message">{{ data.message }}</span>
    </script>
```

Now, I know these can be referenced with `wp.media.template('uploader-status-error')( data )` to get html rendered for example, but what type of template is this? I would think this would be underscore since wp-views are Backbone, but it looks like they aren't the [underscore syntax](http://underscorejs.org/#template). Where is this documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an interesting part from http://underscorejs.org/#template

> If ERB-style delimiters aren't your cup of tea, you can change
>   Underscore's template settings to use different symbols to set off
>   interpolated code. Define an **interpolate** regex to match expressions
>   that should be interpolated verbatim, an **escape** regex to match
>   expressions that should be inserted after being HTML-escaped, and an
>   **evaluate** regex to match expressions that should be evaluated without
>   insertion into the resulting string. You may define or omit any
>   combination of the three. For example, to perform Mustache.js-style
>   templating:
>
> ```
> _.templateSettings = {   interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g };
>
> var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!"); template({name: "Mustache"});
> ```
>
> => "Hello Mustache!"

If we check out `/wp-includes/js/wp-util.js` we see how these *interpolate*, *escape* and *evaluate* regular expressions are defined in WordPress:

```
/**
 * wp.template( id )
 *
 * Fetch a JavaScript template for an id, and return a templating function for it.
 *
 * @param  {string} id   A string that corresponds to a DOM element with an id prefixed with "tmpl-".
 *                       For example, "attachment" maps to "tmpl-attachment".
 * @return {function}    A function that lazily-compiles the template requested.
 */
wp.template = _.memoize(function ( id ) {
        var compiled,
                /*
                 * Underscore's default ERB-style templates are incompatible with PHP
                 * when asp_tags is enabled, so WordPress uses Mustache-inspired templating syntax.
                 *
                 * @see trac ticket #22344.
                 */
                options = {
                        evaluate:    /<#([\s\S]+?)#>/g,
                        interpolate: /\{\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}\}/g,
                        escape:      /\{\{([^\}]+?)\}\}(?!\})/g,
                        variable:    'data'
                };

        return function ( data ) {
                compiled = compiled || _.template( $( '#tmpl-' + id ).html(), null, options );
                return compiled( data );
        };
    });
```

and note this comment:

```
/*
 * Underscore's default ERB-style templates are incompatible with PHP
 * when asp_tags is enabled, so WordPress uses Mustache-inspired templating syntax.
 *
```

Here's the relevant ticket [#22344](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22344) and discussion about it.

Comment: Good info. I wonder why Underscore didn't change to this syntax if it always breaks with PHP asp-style tags.

Comment: good question, and similarly using it with asp or embedded ruby files (erb) ;-)  @NoBugs